# How can I select several different tables that are connected to the table I want to make 3 different dropdowns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am making a form where I create 1 student and that student has to choose 3 different languages. Each of the languages he chooses is associated to a table.(Those language tables are also connected to others to perform the same function).

This is the image from table plus of the table I created https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUrpW.png

I am having problems to be able to call the 3 tables at the same time (Lengua_V, Lengua_P, Lengua_M). To call 1 table and get the languages I have no problem but I have a problem to call the three tables at the same time.

This is the code I have written to make the query. I have try with different commands but I do not find the solution

```php
<?php 
    $db = conectarDB();

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Lengua_V ...";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $consulta);

    
    $id = '';
    $nombre = '';
    $apellido1 = '';
    $apellido2 = '';
    //$posgrado = '';
    $lenguaVid = '';
    //$lenguaPid = '';
    //$lenguaMid = '';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

        $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nombre']); 
        $apellido1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['apellido1']);
        $apellido2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['apellido2']);
        //$posgrado = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['$posgrado']);
        $lenguaVid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lengua_v']);
        // $lenguaPid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lengua_p']);
        // $lenguaMid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lengua_m']);

         
         $query = " INSERT INTO Alumno ".
"(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, lenguaVid, lenguaPid, lenguaMid) ".
"VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido1', '$apellido2', '$lenguaVid', '$lenguaPid', '$lenguaMid' ) ";


        $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if($resultado) {

            header('Location: /admin/alumnos/alumnos.php'); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use 3 different tables. Put everything in a single table where the language is a column.

Comment: @helle this is the structure of the table https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqzwg.png where I want to and the values of the other 3 tables. Maybe I'm doing it wrong as you said.

Comment: pls update your question. I wont follow a random link :D (https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables ;) )

Comment: @helle apologices for my previous post. It is the first time I use stackoverflow.

The link in my question it is just the png that I tried to post but stack transform in a link because I dont have level 10 yet. It is the image of the structure of the table from tableplus

Answer (score 0):

use UNION

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM Lengua_V
UNION
SELECT * FROM Lengua_P
UNION
SELECT * FROM Lengua_M";
```

check docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: I tried with that but still doesn't work. It only show the values of the table Lengua_V in its drop down but not in the other ones. I show below the code I'm using.